# How to share Image-Url to Facebook, twitter and Instagram in Next JS

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, nextjs-image, twitter-api-v2

I am implementing a Next js Dapp and in it HTML canvas is used to edit the image. I have a page where the User can upload their picture and edit it using canvas.

Now using the image received, in the IPFS cid url,
needs to be shared on social media like Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram.
image is in blob format

Comment: Hi, how did you come about solving this? I found a package called 'next-share' but it doesn't seem to be able to send pictures